# Proving this quadrilateral is a rhombus

Tags: geometry

[image]

So to show that this shape is a rhombus we need to show that all the side lengths are equal. I think that we can show that $\Delta TNO \cong \Delta TSR$ and from this get that $TR=NT$.

I don't know though, if somebody could show me how to do this that'd be great! Thanks a ton, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Answer of Charles is exactly what you asked for: how to show that $TR=NT$. Of course it is needed also to show that quadrilateral is parallelogram. Using sum of angles one can show that $\angle NTR+\angle N=180°$, then $TR\parallel NP$. In the same way one can show that $NT\parallel PR$. Then $NTRP$ is parallelogram. Other approach to show that this is rombus is to use formula for area of parallelogram: $S=NP\cdot TO=PR\cdot TS\Rightarrow NP=PR$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\angle N\cong\angle R$ and $\angle TSR\cong \angle TON = 90$, $\angle NTO\cong\angle STR$. Thus all three angles of $\triangle NOT$ and $\triangle RST$ are equal, so one congruent side (TO and TS) gives us congruence.

Comment: Does this complete the proof that it's a Rhombus? what is the characterizing property of a Rhombus that you are using?

Comment: Can you use the fact that parallelogram with two consecutive, congruent sides is a rhombus?